# Can I charge my iPad and use a 30-pin accessory at the same time?

Tags: charging, accessories, lightning, charger

I use iJam to record my guitar into GarageBand on my iPad. iJam connects via the 30-pin connector. Before long, my iPad's battery drains. Is there a way to charge the iPad and use iJam at the same time? It seems a male 30-pin to two female 30-pins splitter cable isn't so simple because I can't find one anywhere.

Comment: I think you're out of luck here. 30-pins splitter cables don't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The cableJive dockStubz](http://www.cablejive.com/products/dockStubz.html) may do the trick. Designed to extend the port in bulky cases, it features a MicroUSB port on the side to charge with older accessories that don't support charging.

MicroUSB should also support an iPad charge, though it may be very slow. See [here](http://store.apple.com/uk/question/answers/product/MD099ZM/A?pqid=QK49UU9CFK7DC9X7TCH4HF9DJTJ4KT4KJKTTJHFAK27FT97KP) for someone saying they can charge their iPad with a MicroUSB adapter (admittedly officially supplied by Apple, but the point is the protocol and cable can handle it). Worst case it will say "not charging" and will charge in sleep, and when not charging the drain will at least be significantly slowed. You will probably need to plug the microUSB adapter into a high power USB port – ideally the iPad 10W charger itself.

I can't guarantee this would work but, were I in your situation, I'd give it a shot and let us know. You could always return the adapter if it didn't suit your needs.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try this when I can. Mentioning using USB reminded me, iJam has a second cable for the Mac that is USB (not micro) rather than a 30-pin. Would this give me more options? Is there a male 30-pin to female 30-pin/usb splitter out there?

Answer (score 0):

It works. I tried it and it kept the ipad charged while I used my iRig HD 30 pin connector.  The only issue I did have was that if it got even bumped a little it would come slightly loose and would not charge or worse would loosen the iRig from the ipad creating a very loud feed back and crackle.  Your best bet is a Griffin Studio Connect.  $39 from Sweetwater music.  I bought in and its terrific for home use.  If you want to use it in a live music situation I might go for Begringers iPad Dock.  Its $99 but worth every penny.